# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for the soln

Tags: java

This program is throwing  `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Prime numbers in a single long string: "2357111317192329..."

**Test cases**

```
Inputs:
    (int) n = 0
Output:
    (string) "23571"

Inputs:
    (int) n = 3
Output:
    (string) "71113"
```

---

```
public class Answer {
        public static String answer(int n) {

        int i = 0;
        int num = 0;
        String primeNumbers = "";
        char[] ar = new char[5];
        for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
                if (i % num == 0) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }
            if (counter == 2) {

                primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i;
            }
        }
        ar[0] = primeNumbers.charAt(n);
        ar[1] = primeNumbers.charAt(n + 1);
        ar[2] = primeNumbers.charAt(n + 2);
        ar[3] = primeNumbers.charAt(n + 3);
        ar[4] = primeNumbers.charAt(n + 4);

        return String.valueOf(ar);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to debug to find out where it's going out of bounds and why. Have you done any debugging yet?

Comment: Try printout the "primeNumbers" and "n". You will quickly see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution:

```
    public class Answer {
            public static String answer(int n) {
                StringBuilder primeNumberString = new StringBuilder(0);
                int currentPrimeNumber = 2;

                while (primeNumberString.length() < n+5) {
                    primeNumberString.append(currentPrimeNumber);
                    currentPrimeNumber++;
                    for (int index = 2; index < currentPrimeNumber; index++) {
                        if (currentPrimeNumber % index == 0) {
                            currentPrimeNumber++;
                            index = 2;
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return primeNumberString.toString().substring(n, n+5)
        }
    }
```

=======================================================

**EDIT**

The problem statement suggests that the required output from the method you have written should be a string of length 5 and it should be from 'n' to 'n+4'.

Our goal should be to come up with a solution that gives us the string from n to n+4 using as less resources as possible and as fast as possible.

In the approach you have taken, you are adding in your string, all the prime numbers between 0 and 10000. Which comes up to about 1,229 prime numbers. The flaw in this approach is that if the input is something like 0. You are still building a string of 1,229 prime numbers which is totally unnecessary. If the input is something like 100000 then the error you are facing occurs, since you don't have a big enough string.

The best approach here is to build a string up to the required length which is n+5. Then cut the substring out of it. It's simple and efficient.

Comment: explication of your solution will gives you more up-votes, so please explain why this work?

Comment: sorry, was in a hurry, will do

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't generate enough length of the string and given value out of your length of string. 
I would recommend you to check your program on max value of given N. 
Also I would recommend you to not use String (read about creating a new object each time when you concatenate String) and simplify the second loop.

```
public static String answer(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    char[] ar = new char[5];
    for (int i = 2; i <= 10000; i++) {
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int j = 2; j*j <= i; j++) {
            if(i%j==0) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            sb.append(i);
        }
    }
    ar[0] = sb.charAt(n);
    ar[1] = sb.charAt(n + 1);
    ar[2] = sb.charAt(n + 2);
    ar[3] = sb.charAt(n + 3);
    ar[4] = sb.charAt(n + 4);

    return String.valueOf(ar);
}
```